# Is inline JavaScript good or bad?

Tags: html, javascript, inlining

I've currently switched from WordPress to [Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/) and an external developer is rebuilding my site.

One thing I notice is that each time he invokes AJAX / jQuery the Yii way, it embeds <strike>inserts JavaScript inline</strike> in the web page. Although it seems the JavaScript code is placed below the footer, it's still inline.

In general, it seems that JavaScript code is more frequently being put inside the webpage. I've always been thought that JavaScript scripts should, as much as possible, be placed in JavaScript files. Is this a coming "new" trend? Or should I still try to keep JavaScript code in separate files?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _it inserts JavaScript inline in the web page_?

Comment: Inline code = javascript code inside html page. 
Insert = Yii PHP ads js code to html page

Comment: For the sake of others who find this question and are thinking of things like `<a onClick="function(){/* do stuff */}
">Click Here</a>` This, I understand, is considered VERY bad and one should seperate their code from their HTML See: [This article](http://www.unicodegirl.com/from-inline-events-to-addeventlistener.html)

Comment: Um... no, I don't think that's so bad. You'll see a lot of that if you are using a framework like Angular. It's more in the direction of having 20+ lines of inline javascript code rather than having the code in separate files.

Comment: @Steven the difference is that Angular uses its own "angular expressions" which applies for the scope of the controller or directive, declared on a parent element, "normal" onClick javascript references the global window.* which i think is horrible and becomes completely unmanageable on bigger projects. ( If you do it by hand )

Comment: @user1066946 http://t.co/j1RpJgwoku :-)

Comment: @Kos You should really just try angularJS, maybe if people don't understand how it works and are looking at it it'll most likely look the same. The point is that it's incredibly hard to refactor javascript on a large codebase without maintaining structure, and that's tough with onclick.

Comment: Hahaha great question! :)

Comment: @user1066946 I really like using Angular, I just observed that the "semantic web" has made a circle (in terms of keeping some glue code next to the DOM)

Comment: "Although it seems the JavaScript code is placed below the footer, it's still inline." - It sounds as if you are referring to _embedded_ JavaScript, rather than "inline" JavaScript (which TecBrat refers to).

Comment: Thanks @w3d. I was mixing embedded and inline. Even though it does both, I was primarily referring to embedded code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inline JavaScript increases download times for the page, which is not good. With a call to a `.js` file, at least these can be parallel calls and content download times decreased. Yes there are times where it is okay to put JavaScript directly in the HTML code, but you are often better off off-loading this as much as possible.

Keep in mind that page download times (that is, the HTML) and not all the resource calls affect the metrics that affect ranking (albeit as PageRank or in the SERPs it does not matter). The point is, it affects a sites performance for SEO however it manifests.

Comment: Negotiating a second connection to a presumably same host to download the same amount of data is faster than within the active stream? usually if you get, say, 50Kbps on a file to a host, starting a second session may cut it so that both are now 25Kbps.  Unless the host is throttling per connection for some reason.

Comment: There is a con to external files though. If not done properly, you create DOMblocking code, ie the doc.ready trigger is slower, which affects _percieved_ speed. But if properly done, external is the way to go

Comment: `.js` files are better for caching, it does not make sense that two connections to the same host would magically make your download speed larger.

Comment: The thought of dividing the bandwidth, while I understand your logic and it is not entirely wrong, is a bit misleading. The HTML is smaller taking less time and any subsequent call can actually wait.

Comment: if you are loking for time, you are wrong to look at bandwidth. look at profiler at loading times: normally connection times are 10-100x BIGGER than real data exchange time.
this mean that FRAGMENTATION is a real problem, and using an external, dedicated, file for really small js may be worst that inline. Inline is better on browser that does not do real parallelization

Comment: I do not disagree. There is a balance to be made. A single rule for one over the other cannot be made because there are considerations that vary from site to site.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that, opposed to images, script files are downloaded synchronously, that means, the page loading stops until the script is fully loaded and initialized.

Comment: Good point. I always advocate smaller JavaScript, but will anyone listen? Noooooooo.... ;-)

Comment: This answer should not be the accepted answer.  Inline javascript does *not* necessarily increase download time for a page, or even render-time for a page. There are multiple factors that need to be accounted for in this question:  How much javascript? One line? One function? or 1000k?  How many http requests are involved in getting your external scripts?  If inline, where in the page is the script located? Is it located in the footer?Is it render-blocking? Etc.

Answer (score 32):

On my currency conversion site, the majority of sessions are single page views.   This is because users can do their currency calculation directly on the landing page (all the calculation is handled client side with JavaScript.)

My page downloads and renders in about half the time when all resources (css, js, and even [images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs)) are inline in the page.   Because so few of my users view multiple pages, I wouldn't benefit much from some of these resources being cached between page views.

My site is not typical.  Most sites have multiple pages per session and large images that would make my technique less applicable. There is no one correct solution to this question; it depends on the site. You need to [measure it yourself](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights_extensions) based on the typical behavior of your users.

Answer (score 14):

It's not necessarily bad to have JavaScript within your HTML file but you must make a judgement call on it.

It *is* bad if you have a large amount of JavaScript being used across multiple pages. In that case, the JavaScript should be in an external, compressed, and cachable file and if your site has very heavy traffic you should make use of a CDN.

However, if you have a small amount of JavaScript the saving of putting it in an external file might be negated by the fact you need to make an additional HTTP request to retrieve it. In this instance it would be more efficient to keep the JavaScript in your page.

Then again, if this same small snippet of JavaScript is used on multiple pages it would be beneficial to place it in an external file to take advantage of caching.

Ultimately you must weigh up the size of the JavaScript against the overhead of making additional HTTP requests. For the most part, for an 'average' site, it probably isn't going to make a whole lot of difference just putting it in an external file.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a Yii developer and I can tell you, that *Yii has nothing to do with this*. It is *completely on developer side*, whether he or she put Javascript code to a separate file and register it with HTML (view) page with [`CClientScript::registerScriptFile`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript/#registerScriptFile-detail) method or put it directly to view (HTML) code and register it using [`CClientScript::registerScript`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript/#registerScript-detail) method.

As per your answer, most (professional?) Yii developers strongly vote for first approach, that is -- keeping as much Javascript code in separate files as possible. So, this is most certainly **not** a new trend of coding, but rather a bad developer practice. At least, that's how it is seen in Yii community.

**EDIT**: Actually, I forgot about most important argument. Yii (as well as most other professional PHP frameworks) is build upon [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern (actually:  architectural pattern). And the same pattern can be used in fronted: HTML code is the model (data), CSS is the view (decorator) and Javascript is the controller. All of them put *into separate files*, `.js` and `.css` files -- minified, obsfucated and gzipped in the best scenario.

When you build up your Yii application, you can break the MVC pattern and keep everything in the same file. The question is -- is it worth doing so, what are the benefits (none?) and where will that lead you? You can use the same argumentation, when asking, whether to keep JS code inline or not?

Comment: Ok. The developer seems to use 3rd party widgets for everything; Autocomplete, ajax image uploads etc. All this adds inline js.

Comment: No, I can't agree. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap in my Yii applications (probably Yii's biggest extension and huge set of widgets) as well as many other Yii's extensions and none of them uses inline JS. Your developer would have to be really lucky to find widgets and extensions, that uses only inline Javascript. You have to be quite experienced in Yii to start writing own extensions (with exception of those few, really poorly written) and even semi-experienced Yii developer uses inline code as last of options, if everything else fails.

Comment: Using 3rd party extensions and widgets in Yii is a great idea (you don't have to invent the wheel again). But, using inline JS code in Yii application or extension really is a bad attitude. So either force your developer to write better code / use better extensions and widgets or... get a better developer! :]

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. Besides Stackoverflow, where can I find a good Yii community?

Comment: At [Yii forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/). Most pages are freely accessible. Some require to register an account and login. Most Yii developers at Stack Overflow have own accounts at the forum. After nearly six years of existing, Yii framework has earned a large community of developers, so if you look carefully, you should be able to find few Yii developers in your local community or even neighborhood. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

It actually depends on the purpose of the webpage you are developing:

I use a small amount of inline JavaScript, whereas I prefer to go for external JavaScript files if it's big.

Either way, when the page loads JavaScript, it has to be executed first. The best practice is to use external JavaScript so it doesn't lengthen your page content. It also makes debugging easier.

Answer (score 2):

The answer actually depends on what is being done.

If you notice inline JavaScript that is used across the website (e.g. a widget that shows inside the header on all pages of the website) then it would be appropriate to move it to a "common" JavaScript file.

In fact, I would move as much JavaScript to a common JavaScript file as possible even if it were used on a single page. I would configure the server to send strong caching and compression headers for JavaScript files; which reduces the size of page(s) but not increase the size of JavaScript file by much.

On the other hand, if the JavaScript is simply a bunch of configuration options/initialization e.g.:

```
$(function () {
    myplugin({
        images: ["img1", "img2", "img3"]
    });
});
```

where for some reason it was not possible to move the code to external JavaScript file (e.g. when the image parameters are coming from database) I would keep it in inline. Having said that, I would choose third party plugins that are "unobtrusive" (or convert them as such).

Answer (score 2):

These answers miss the mark. Have a look at [Inline caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_caching).

Since Yii is coded in PHP, a common (or perhaps uncommon) PHP pattern you'll find is that developers will sometimes write PHP code to generate Javascript code dynamically at the server - based on some state, condition or value known by the server - and then send it all to the client in one batch, allowing the client to execute the function and skip some of the computation that has already been done by the server.

Instead of sending a whole bunch of generic Javascript functions in a .js file to the client which have no context until provided with data (data which may be sitting on the server and require a round trip), we can "bake-in" the context/data as part of the Javascript function. This is thrifty because it means you're sending the functionality/data together, and only sending the functionality/data that a client may need at the time, instead of sending the whole app on the first page load. It also means you don't have to expose your entire app to being easily downloaded and reverse-engineered on the first page load because you are only injecting small portions of functionality that each individual client may need at the time. Not sure how well that bodes for SEO, but I'm sure it can be optimized accordingly. Reducing the number of HTTP requests by having some inline Javascript can be useful, it just depends.

Consider the case of an end-user writing a page in some CMS software using a WYSIWYG editor. How is this user going to add new functionality to the page when they don't have access to your source .js files on the server? They switch to the HTML tab and use inline Javascript.

Not all inline Javascript is bad; sometimes onclick is fine too. As a general recommendation, avoid writing inline Javascript and you'll be on your way to building good habits.

References:

- [Inline caching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_caching)
- [Optimizing dynamic JavaScript with inline caches](https://github.com/sq/JSIL/wiki/Optimizing-dynamic-JavaScript-with-inline-caches)
- [Explaining JavaScript VMs in JavaScript - Inline Caches](http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/06/03/explaining-js-vms-in-js-inline-caches.html)
- [Why Should I Avoid Inline Scripting? (see MainMa's & user1389596's answer)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting)

Answer (score 0):

Normally inline JS code is bad, as the others said before me.

But I think of a use case where inline JS is **better**.

Think of a CMS which inserts a JS driven gallery. The gallery maybe done in jQuery. It is identified by an id attribute, which is not only unique on the page, but also unique throughout the whole site. In this case—I think—inline JS would be better, because the JS code is used only on one page and you have no HTTP overhead